# High CPU usage by Google assistant on RPi

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have installed [Google assistant on RPi](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/#embed) but my board becomes hot due high constant CPU usage:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
  717 pi        20   0  240432  63868  17740 S  24,1  6,7  17:57.44 googlesamp+
  996 pi        20   0    8104   3196   2740 R   1,4  0,3   0:16.61 top
```

Is this normal?